# invalid identifier in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write the SQL to copy a row from one table to another but I keep getting an invalid identifier in the WHERE clause. I'm using oracle apex.

Here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO CRIMECLOSED (crimeClosedID, crimeName, crimeDate, crimeNotes, 
   outsideSourceDescription, dateClosed, relatedCrimes, 
   staffID, crimeTypeID, locationID)  
SELECT CRIMEOPEN.crimeOpenID, CRIMEOPEN.crimeName, CRIMEOPEN.crimeDate, 
       CRIMEOPEN.crimeNotes,  CRIMEOPEN.outsideSourceDescription, CURDATE(), 
       CRIMEOPEN.relatedCrimes, CRIMEOPEN.staffID, CRIMEOPEN.crimeTypeID, 
       CRIMEOPEN.locationID
FROM CRIMEOPEN
WHERE CRIMEOPEN.crimeOpenID = '1';
```

CRIMEOPEN table

```
CREATE TABLE  "CRIMEOPEN" 
(   "crimeOpenID" VARCHAR2(5), 
"crimeName" VARCHAR2(20), 
"crimeDate" DATE, 
"crimeNotes" VARCHAR2(200), 
"outsideSourceDescription" VARCHAR2(200), 
"relatedCrimes" VARCHAR2(5), 
"staffID" VARCHAR2(5), 
"crimeTypeID" VARCHAR2(5), 
"locationID" VARCHAR2(5), 
 CONSTRAINT "CRIMEOPEN_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("crimeOpenID") ENABLE
 )
```

The error I get is:

> ORA-00904: "CRIMEOPEN"."CRIMEOPENID": invalid identifier

I think the error is trying to say that 'crimeOpenID' is not a column in 'CRIMEOPEN' but it is. 
Any help please?

Comment: include your table design for CRIMEOPEN

Comment: Are you really using MySQL with Oracle Apex?

Comment: Why you need Alias name here you can remove those

Comment: Added table definition

Comment: Your life would be a lot easier without cased object names...

Comment: Don't use quoted identifiers. They create much more trouble than they are worth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use double quotes when declaring the columns of the table then the same format needs to be used also when "using" the columns in various statements.

So in order to fix the issue you should wrap all columns in double quotes in the select statement (something like below - applied only to the select statement).

```
INSERT INTO CRIMECLOSED (crimeClosedID, crimeName, crimeDate, crimeNotes, 
   outsideSourceDescription, dateClosed, relatedCrimes, 
   staffID, crimeTypeID, locationID)  
SELECT "CRIMEOPEN"."crimeOpenID", "CRIMEOPEN"."crimeName", "CRIMEOPEN"."crimeDate", 
       "CRIMEOPEN"."crimeNotes",  "CRIMEOPEN"."outsideSourceDescription", CURDATE(), 
       "CRIMEOPEN"."relatedCrimes", "CRIMEOPEN"."staffID", "CRIMEOPEN"."crimeTypeID", 
       "CRIMEOPEN"."locationID"
FROM "CRIMEOPEN"
WHERE "CRIMEOPEN"."crimeOpenID" = '1';
```

Comment: This fixes the error above but now Im getting the error: ORA-00904: "LOCATIONID": invalid identifier

Comment: @user1056798, then you should probably do the same thing for the columns in the insert statemnt - if these were declared in the same way, using double quotes, then wrap these in double quotes when using them.